# assign sequential number to each set of duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, ms-access-2010, autonumber

I've been searching for an easy solution to a pretty trivial problem. I have an huge set of records (~120,000) that I need to screen for duplicates, assign a sequential number to each set of duplicates, like `Assign#` below:
[image]

Eventually, I am trying to achieve this:
[image]

I use `P1`, `P2`, and `P3` fields as a set of sort parameters in query (ascending/descending) to determine the best/top `Name` for each set of identical NCBI hits.
I tried a lot of things already and my main problem is that access freezes half way through and I don't really know if the script is functional.

```
FROM [sortquery] 
WHERE ((([sortquery].Name) In 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 [sortquery].Name 
    FROM [sortquery] AS Dupe 
    WHERE Dupe.NCBI=[sortquery].NCBI 
    ORDER BY Dupe.NCBI
))) 
ORDER BY [sortquery].NCBI;
```

I am open to any suggestion and corrections! Thanks for any help =)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS Access?  They are very different databases.

Comment: He says in the question that "access freezes half way through".  My guess is he is using Access.

Comment: Yes, I am using Access 2007-2013

Answer (score 1):

The traditional method is to count:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   (Select Count(*)
   From Sortquery As S
   Where S.NCBI = Sortquery.NCBI 
       And S.P1 * 1000 + S.P3 >= Sortquery.P1 * 1000 + Sortquery.P3) As [Assign#]
FROM 
    [sortquery] 
ORDER BY
    NCBI Asc,
    P1 Desc,
    P3 Desc,
    [Name] Asc,
    [Assign#] Asc
```

Comment: Thank Gustav, but count option doesn't work for some reason. I am starting to think that maybe I am setting the count(*) to a wrong field. I used your suggested script and the result had most of the fields marked "1". The only places that had "2" where actual full record duplicates (all 5 fields); whereas, My goal is to basically to count each set of "NCBI" field duplicates.

Comment: You are right. See edit with NCBI only and relating to P1 and P3.

Comment: I tried that too ))) it only assigns the total count to each dup record. I think there has to be an autonumber function for each set of duplicate records, counting duplicate data just comes back with totals instead of sequential order per duplicate set of records.

Comment: The count will be 1, 2, 3 and will thus be the assign#.